# Handling CSV with timezone-aware and timezone-naive datetime column

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a pandas dataframe that is imported from a csv that looks like this:

```
|date time|id|value|
|------|-------|---------|
|2019-10-08T01:00:00+01:00|1|35|
|2019-10-08T02:00:00+01:00|1|32|
|2019-10-08T03:00:00+01:00|1|33|
|2019-12-08T01:00:00Z|1|25|
|2019-12-08T01:00:00Z|1|15|
|2019-12-08T01:00:00Z|1|25|
```

When I try to do an aggregation like this:

```
data.groupby([data['Date'].dt.date]).agg(['mean', 'count'])
```

I get an error like this:

```
ValueError: Cannot mix tz-aware with tz-naive values
```

An additional wrinkle is that, it is important to use these date values and not the UTC values as I would be doing peak-hour analysis based on the local (British) time. What's the best way to fix this?

Comment: as side notes, **#1** the "Z" in e.g. "2019-12-08T01:00:00Z" denotes UTC, which would be incorrect if the data is coming from a specific time zone as Europe/London (should be "+00:00" then instead). **#2** even if "Z" would be "+00:00" in the example, pandas would not process this in a clean manner (as of v1.2.5); you'd end up with a mixed UTC offset column and `dt` accessor not being available. Nevertheless, the solution I suggest below would work.

Comment: Yes, the data seems to be incorrect. Unfortunately, that's how I am receiving the data from the provider. The BST times come with the +01:00, but the GMT ones come with the Z, and not +00:00. But yes, your solution worked fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for given example with column `date time` as string datatype,

```
df['date time']
0    2019-10-08T01:00:00+01:00
1    2019-10-08T02:00:00+01:00
2    2019-10-08T03:00:00+01:00
3         2019-12-08T01:00:00Z
4         2019-12-08T01:00:00Z
5         2019-12-08T01:00:00Z
Name: date time, dtype: object
```

**convert to datetime datatype using [pd.to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) with keyword `utc=True`, *then* convert to the appropriate time zone:**

```
df['date time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date time'], utc=True).dt.tz_convert('Europe/London')
```

to get

```
df['date time']
0   2019-10-08 01:00:00+01:00
1   2019-10-08 02:00:00+01:00
2   2019-10-08 03:00:00+01:00
3   2019-12-08 01:00:00+00:00
4   2019-12-08 01:00:00+00:00
5   2019-12-08 01:00:00+00:00
Name: date time, dtype: datetime64[ns, Europe/London]
```

Now the `groupby` works as intended:

```
df.groupby([df['date time'].dt.date]).agg(['mean', 'count'])
             id            value      
           mean count       mean count
date time                             
2019-10-08    1     3  33.333333     3
2019-12-08    1     3  21.666667     3
```