# Chnaging "DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM" to Seconds and getting error Cannot subtract tz-naive and tz-aware datetime-like objects

Tags: python, csv, datetime

I have a CSV file with date in a single column as "DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM" eg: 23/05/2022 12:07. I converter it into seconds and get the following Error

```
  File "C:\pandas\core\arrays\datetimes.py", line 735, in _sub_datetime_arraylike
    raise type(error)(new_message) from error

TypeError: Cannot subtract tz-naive and tz-aware datetime-like objects
```

any idea why?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Handling CSV with timezone-aware and timezone-naive datetime column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68182325/handling-csv-with-timezone-aware-and-timezone-naive-datetime-column)

Comment: could you maybe clarify: "*I converter it into seconds*" - how?